# Animated bar using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am trying to create Animated Bar chart using Matplotlib. Was able to product static plot. Nit able to animate the series. Can anyone please help. I sense something wrong with FuncAnimation.
Thanks in advance.

Code below
\\

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 8))
def draw_barchart(Day):
    df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Kedar/MEDD/District.xlsx')
    df = df.sort_values(by='Day',ascending=True)
    current_date = 37
    dff = df[df['Day'].eq(current_date)].sort_values(by='Death_rate_new', ascending=True).tail(10)
#    dff = dff[::-1]   # flip values from top to bottom
    ax.clear()
    ax.barh(dff['Area'], dff['Death_rate_new'], color=colors)
    # iterate over the values to plot labels and values (Tokyo, Asia, 38194.2)
    for i, (value, name) in enumerate(zip(dff['Death_rate_new'], dff['Area'])):
        ax.text(value, i,     value,           ha='left')   # 38194.2: value
    # Add date right middle portion of canvas
    #ax.text(1, 0.4, current_date, transform=ax.transAxes, size=46, ha='right')
    # ... polished styles
    ax.text(1, 0.4, current_date, transform=ax.transAxes, color='#777777', size=46, ha='right', weight=800)
    ax.text(0, 1.06, 'Death rate (%)', transform=ax.transAxes, size=12, color='#777777')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}'))
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='#777777', labelsize=12)
    ax.set_yticks(['Area'])
    ax.margins(0, 0.01)
    ax.grid(which='major', axis='x', linestyle='-')
    ax.set_axisbelow(True)
    ax.text(0, 1.12, 'Death Rate for Major Municipal Corporation in Maharasthra from 4th April to 25th May',
            transform=ax.transAxes, size=24, weight=600, ha='left')
    ax.text(1, 0, 'by @kedarpatgaonkar; credit @pratapvardhan', transform=ax.transAxes, ha='right',
            color='#777777', bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=0.8, edgecolor='white'))
    plt.box(False) 
draw_barchart(37)

import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from IPython.display import HTML
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 8))
animator = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, draw_barchart, frames=range(1,37)) 
HTML(animator.to_jshtml())
```

\\

Answer (score 0):

I have got an answer to this. 
'current_date = 37' was something which was causing an issue. I also have used FuncAnimation successfully and using ffmpeg exported it as .mp4 file.

Thanks